# Issues with Webalizer cron job throwing error due to file cannot open - how to Fix?

Tags: cron, webalizer

So I have a newly installed server running Ubuntu 14.04 with the default install of Sentora the free open source control panel. I did not make any customization to webalizer or cron. So I am unsure why this error is being thrown. Any ideas?

Here is the email I receive from the server to the root user's email address.

> Subject: Cron  test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
>
> Body:
>
> /etc/cron.daily/webalizer:
>   /etc/cron.daily/webalizer: 17: /etc/cron.daily/webalizer: Â continue: not found
>   awk: fatal: cannot open file `/etc/webalizer/*.conf' for reading (No such file or directory)

The direcotry `/etc/webalizer` only has one file in it: `webalizer.conf.sample`. And searching the entire server for a file of webalizer.conf comes up with nothing. So is something misconfigured? Should I just remove this cron job or something? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Webalizer is not configured correctly, as there's no configuration file. To use it, copy `webalizer.conf.sample` to `webalizer.conf` and modify it to fit your setup and needs.
You can also create more than one configuration file with `.conf`, as the cron job runs through all `*.conf` (`/etc/cron.daily/webalizer`):

```
for i in ${WEBALIZER_CONFDIR}/*.conf; do
    [...]
```

And if there's no file matching this bash-glob, bash will through an error by default.

---

In case you don't want to use webalizer, uninstall it using `apt-get purge webalizer`.

Comment: Thank you for your post! Well, here is the interesting thing. I am running Sentora (hosting control panel) on this server, and I'm assuming Sentora installed Webalizer as its using it. It currently works and I can view stats of my sites. But the problem is, I did a find -name webalizer.conf and I can't find that file anywhere on my server. So I don't even know how this is being used. So should I just remove the webalizer file from the cron.daily folder since it can't run anyways. That shouldn't hurt anything right?

Comment: If you refer to a control panel, the entire question is off-topic here, as their existence changes the behavior of the system and it's programs in many ways. Please refer to the documentation of your control panel to find out, where the configuration can be found. Second, yes, *I guess* that deactivating/removing the cronjob should solve the problem, but can't guarantee anything, for the reasons described in the beginning of this comment.